# What causes an apache 400?

Tags: apache-2.4

is anyone aware of any official or unofficial docs on why apache returns a 400 status code? I am aware that this is due to a bad client request, but what constitutes a bad client request? I know things like large request size and invalid characters can cause a 400, but I would like some sort of definitive list.

E.g. the o'reilly "definitive guide on apache" does not give this detail.

Thanks!
Damien

Comment: AFAIK and almost by definition:  there can't be a definitive list what causes a 400 response as that response code is for anything that gets thrown at Apache httpd, that possibly  sort of looks like a HTTP request, but which can't be parsed as a valid request. It is the equivalent of `WTF*#K!`

Comment: Usually when the request doesn't follow the defined format `method uri protocol/version` (e.g. `GET / HTTP/1.1`), it gives out 400 and *logs the garbage request line*. So what was logged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK and almost by definition: there can't be a definitive list what causes a `400` response as that response code is for anything that gets thrown at Apache httpd, which can't be parsed as a valid request.

That may be something that *"appears"* to resemble a valid request or can be complete rubbish.

The `400` response is the equivalent of `WTF*#K`!

As commented by @NikitaKipriyanov the apache (error) log typically records what request line triggered the 400 response.

---

Historically a HTTP request line is terminated with a **carriage return and a line feed** and so your log typically shows whatever was thrown at Apache until it received the first carriage return and a line feed.

A quick search for 400 responses in my apache logs shows a number or recurring "bad requests" types:

- The most common: a **valid looking [HTTP 1.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#Request_syntax) a request line**, that consists of the **case-sensitive request method**, a **space**, the requested **URL**, another **space** and the **protocol version** such as:
  `"GET / HTTP/1.1"`
  that most likely got rejected because the `Host:` header wasn't included in the request and that header is mandatory in HTTP/1.1
- Fairly common: **binary (handshake) data** that appears as escaped hex such as for example

  - `"\x16\x03\x01\x01\xfc\x01"` which in this example is caused by trying to establish a TLS 1.2 connection on the plain HTTP port 80 (or any other port, even 443, when no TLS is configured there)
  - `"\x16\x03\x01` is a similar TLS 1 / 1.1 handshake
  - `\x16\x03"` is a similar SSL3 handshake
  - in many other variations
  - or even just a `"\n"`
- Attempts to connect with a **completely different protocol** than HTTP(S) to the web server ports i.e.

  - `"SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4"` probing if SSH is offered on a web server port (a trick often used by sysadmins and users to circumvent a corporate firewall)
  - `"SSTP_DUPLEX_POST /sra_{BA195980-CD49-458b-9E23-C84EE0ADCD75}/ HTTP/1.1"` probing for a VPN end-point supporting the [SSTP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Socket_Tunneling_Protocol)
  - and others.